# Could I boil water by spinning it in a highly insulated container?

Tags: everyday-life, work

Let's say I have a large, closed, insulating  container that is half filled with water. There is a paddle coming into the container that is attached to a bicycle-power motor outside.

If I just biked for a while, would I eventually heat up the water to 100 C just by imparting kinetic energy on to the water molecules through the paddle? This would be considered positive work on the system.

Answer (score 2):

If your insulation is perfect and your fluid is dissipative (so there is some friction inside the container) sure. Your paddle is doing work which cant escape the container. This leads to increasing temperature. So yes then it would be possible to boil water (also see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160114/can-a-liquid-boil-in-a-closed-container?rq=1))

But of course in reality if the water is boiling or not depends on how good your insulation is.